# Center text in textview is changing the view size based on text length

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create equally sized boxes with centered text. I am running into weird issue. When I create the boxed without the gravity.center then I am getting the following

[image]

When I add the the attribute center, I get the following

[image]

The text is nicely centered but the views are shifted for some reason when text size changes. Even if I cut the text down to one word then the box is bigger then everything else

Here is my layout.. What is it going on? How can I solve it?

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
           <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="Name of Player Added" />

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:layout_gravity="top"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="Name of Player Added" />           
          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" /> 
          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" /> 

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is because you have given height width hardcoded and in the last 2 textview you have more data if you remove some you will find them same as the first 2

Comment: there are 2 options increase your height width or decrease your text

Comment: This text will be filled in dynamically later. I need the box to be this exact width or height.. Like I said even if I decrease the text, the misalignment will stay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added android:gravity="center" in LinearLayout. Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:text="Name of Player Added"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:text="Name of Player Added"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome that works. Mind explaining why this fixed it?

Comment: I don't know actually, I came across the same problem in my app and I just tried it and it worked for me :) But if you get to know the reason then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="4">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:text="Name of Player Added"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:text="Name of Player Added"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this. Hope you will get your desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
           <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="Name of Player Added" />

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:layout_gravity="top"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="Name of Player Added" />           
          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" /> 
          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1"
             android:layout_width="80dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/bg"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
             android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" /> 

        </LinearLayout>
```